# How to assign instances of a class as a property for the same class in the class body?

Tags: python, class-variables

In class `A`, I want some 'special' values to be stored as class properties.  The following doesn't work for understandable reasons:

```
class A:
    
   def __init__(self, msg):
        self.s = msg

   X = A("special message")
```

I could use:

```
class A:
    
   def __init__(self, msg):
        self.s = msg

A.X = A("special message")  # outside of the class
```

But it seems untidy and easily forgotten (suppose class `A` was long).  Is there a neat way to initialize a class variable of A with an instance of A inside the class itself?

Comment: Your second option seems fine. I'm not sure why or by whom you think it will be easily forgotten, but if necessary you could add comments to remind whoever it is of whatever they are supposed to remember.

Comment: It's me that forgets and then takes a while to work out what's happened.  I'm 70 - and neither memory nor concentration are what they were when I first programmed (Fortran 66 - about 1973, then BCPL in 1974).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a neat way to initialize a class variable of A with an instance of A inside the class itself?

**NO**, you can't initialize a class property with an instance of same class **inside the class** ** because the body of your class is executed first and your class is not defined until the execution of body is completed. But maybe you can use a decorator. I'm not sure if you prefer it over `A.X = A("special message")` but here you go:

```py
def add_class_property(name, arg):
    class ClassWrapper:
        def __init__(self, cls):
            self.other_class = cls
            setattr(self, name, cls(arg))

        def __call__(self, *cls_ars):
            return self.other_class(*cls_ars)

    return ClassWrapper


@add_class_property("X", "special message")
class A:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.s = msg


print(A.X.s)

# Output:
# special message
```

If you want to assign multiple instances at once, you can do this:

```py
def add_class_properties(**kwargs):
    class ClassWrapper:
        def __init__(self, cls):
            self.other_class = cls
            for key, val in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, key, cls(val))

        def __call__(self, *cls_ars):
            return self.other_class(*cls_ars)

    return ClassWrapper


@add_class_properties(X="special message", Y="another message")
class A:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.s = msg

print(A.X.s)
print(A.Y.s)
```

```
special message
another message
```

**: You can do it inside the methods of your class, however that's a different thing.